# Download pdf file after form submission in custom-post-type

Tags: php, wordpress, popup, custom-post-type, contact-form-7

I have created my custom post type by using CPT-UI plugin. Then I have create a custom page template in wordpress and list all those posts. When I am adding a new post it will automatically list the post in custom-page-template.
And when somebody click on the listed specific post link (having pdf), the specific pdf gets downloaded. Everything works perfectly well.

When user clicks on the link (custom-field link) to download, a popup will be created which will first ask the user to fill a form and on clicking submit it will download the PDF file in user's local machine.

Find below code to display posts on custom-page-template:

```
<?php 

     $args = array(
      'post_type'   => 'inde_case',
      'posts_per_page' => -1
       );

      query_posts($args);
       ?>

<ul class="case_study_section1 col-md-12 nopadding">

 <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
   <?php $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'inde_case_category');
    if( !empty($terms) ) {

    $term = array_pop($terms);
} 
   ?>
    <li data-category="<?php echo $term->slug; ?>" class="case_study_img col-md-3 col-sm-6">
        <div class="caseSection">

        <div class="imagediv"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></div>
           <div style="width:100%;float:left;">
            <a class="popmake-6981 case_study_pdf"   href="<?php the_field('linkicon'); ?>" >PDF</a>
            <a class="popmake-6981 case_study_title"  href="<?php the_field('linktext'); ?>" ><?php the_title(); ?></a>
           </div>
       </div>

    </li>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

I am using popup maker plugin for popup form on-click through class name as  "popmake-6981" in the above code.

Below jquery to get pdf link on-click:

```
<script> $('.case_study_title').click(function(){ var hrefvalue= $(this).attr("href"); alert(hrefvalue); }); </script>
```

But I don't no how can I interact the above jquery with my contact form 7 or any other way to pass the same stuffs on form submit.

Comment: Hi. Which fields are being submitted through your contact form, and what contact form field is the trigger for the PDF (if I read your question correctly)?

Comment: When user clicks on the link (custom-field link) to download, a popup will be created which will first ask the user to fill a form and on clicking submit it will download the PDF file in user's local machine.

Comment: So are you just looking to trigger an event after the form is submitted?  Sorry, but it's a little unclear.

Comment: Yes, Just want to download a specific pdf file after the form is submitted instead of direct download.

Comment: Ok and is the PDF link in the form somewhere?

Comment: No, It's on link only where I suppose to click to download it. And now it will download directly instead of download only on form submitted.

Comment: PHP is not the answer for this... It's jquery. You'll have to write a script to accomplish this.

Comment: Through jquery, I got the specific link url through on-click event. But this code is working on the same page only. Then how can I interact those with my contact form 7 form which is in wordpress dashboard?

Comment: Can you post your jquery? Please add it to the question

Comment: <script>
 $('.case_study_title').click(function(){
 var hrefvalue= $(this).attr("href");
  alert(hrefvalue);
});
</script>

Comment: By using above jquery, I can get pdf url on click, but I don't know how can I interact with my contact form 7 or any other way to passed on form submit.

Comment: Hi.  Can you edit your question and add both the script and the contact form?  It's hard to follow the script in the comments.

Comment: Question edited. check now.

Comment: URL for your reference: http://indemortgage.staging.wpengine.com/case-study/

Comment: In Short, I am listed some data (thumbnail, pdf link) through custom post type. When user clicks on the link to download, a popup will be created (by popup-maker plugin) which will first ask the user to fill a form and on clicking submit it will download the PDF file in user's local machine.

Comment: So.. you need to do some more setup... I would pass`data-pdf-id` to your form, and make a hidden form field called `pdf-id` which would allow you pass things from A->B.  Once you have a form field that has the PDF post id (or URL) then you can work on using contact form 7 hooks to trigger a download after submit.